Only Happens in dev.azure.com/compay(login, gitkraken, Personal Access Token) TF400893: Unable to contact the server
If I reload multiple times it gets logged or loads the PAT list, but past 2 minutes it shows up message again. I tried updating the time, the credentials manager, different browsers, and clearing cookies, the thing is I can access it from my other laptops, but the main one I don't.
even this page: "https://spsprodcus2.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signout"
example
